# I would like to change the domain name an account I'm hosting using whm

Tags: dns, whm

I have a VPS and read about changing a domain name on WHM. It looks like it is as easy as Opening WHM, making an account modification and changing the olddomain name to the newdomain. Where I'm confused is how to update my newdomain on godaddy.com to point the newdomain to the name server for the hosting account. Can I point the newdomain name to the name servers of the olddomain name? Matt

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your new domain nameserver so that it will start to resolve to your VPS. You have WHM access so you can create new namesevrer with your new domain name like ns1.new-domain and ns2.new-domain with your VPS IP and register that to godaddy panel.